# Xlsxwriter making a chart which skips blank cells

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, xlsxwriter

I am parsing a list of data from Python to Excel. I need to graph the relationship between the objects and time. The objects, however, do not have all column filled. It looks something like below:

[image]

Using XLSXWriter, I was able to graph both Object A and Object B versus Time. My code is something like this:

```
chart.add_series({
            'name': 'Object A',
            'categories': ['Sheet1', 1, 0, 17, 0], # Row 2 -> 18, column 0 (Time)
            'values': ['Sheet1', 1, 1, 17, 1]})    # Row 2 -> 18, column 1 (Object A)
chart.add_series({
            'name': 'Object B',
            'categories': ['Sheet1', 1, 0, 17, 0],
            'values': ['Sheet1', 1, 2, 17, 2]})
chart.show_blanks_as('span')
```

The line "chart.show_blanks_as('span')" has helped me to connect existed data with a line, meaning the "blank" cells are treated as some values on that linear line. But, in the x-axis still displays all value of the x-axis, from 1 to 9.

Is there a way so that the x-axis will only display "Time" values when at least one of the objects has data? (For this example: 1, 2, 2.5, 3, 4.5, 6, 6.5, 7.5). This will make it easier for other users who view the Excel file to know the time when there is actual data.

Comment: You are asking about xlsxwriter but is what you want possible in Excel?

Comment: @jmcnamara : Honestly I am not too sure about this. Couldn't find any examples related to this

Comment: @Ratiasu After a long time, are you still interested in the answer?